# Openshift Connection to closed by remote host

Tags: django, openshift

I am using openshift as my production server for django app. However today I have had trouble running a simple update script that takes about 1 minute to update my database. I got disconnected within few seconds after I run it.

```
Connection to app-domain.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to app-domain.rhcloud.com closed.
```

I tried to run it with `nohup ./script &`, but there is no error log in honup.out (except warning, so I guess it is run but killed). I tried to run it without nohup as well.
I also tried to run it from `./manage.py shell`, logged out as well and script did not finish.
I've read that I might have problem with ssh keys. So I deleted my keys in `~/.ssh/` folder and created new ones with `rhc setup` tool.
Last option that comes to my mind is to add my script to `.openshift/cron/` folder, but it is really bad solution, to create cron every time I want to run something for more than a few seconds (I get disconnected within 5 seconds).
Did openshift implement something to kill processes taking to much cpu for a minute or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been struggling here for 6 hours and just after posting this question I found what was the problem.
I had two models in my script. Stock (8000 objects) and Dividend (240 000 objects). I wanted to save some sql queries and I prefetched dividends for all stocks. After removing `prefetch_related` everything worked.
**So openshift kills process/disconnects you, if you allocate too much memory (RAM) I guess.**